# cargar información de select en input - reactjs

Tags: reactjs

tengo un select en reactjs que me trae una lista de mi api sin problemas pero necesito que al seleccionar un registro de mi select el valor "documento" que trae el registro me lo me lo muestre en un input:

https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-jasper-6j6rvl?file=/src/App.js:0-1020

este es el código que tengo pero no he logrado mostrar el valor del "documento" en un input:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [t4t, setUniversidad] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      const getcountry2 = async () => {
        const req = await fetch(
          `https://aliraweb.com/apiAlira2/cargar_empleados/nombre_trabajador.php?id_empresa_usuario=30`
        );
        const getres2 = await req.json();
        setUniversidad(await getres2);
      };
      getcountry2();
    }, 2000);
    return () => setInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <select
        // name="t4"
        className="form-select"
      >
        <option>--Seleccione --</option>
        {t4t.map((getcon2) => (
          <option key={getcon2.id} value={getcon2.name}>
            {" "}
            {getcon2.documento} - {getcon2.name}{" "}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>

      <br />
      {/*  <input type="text"  value={getcon2.documento} />*/}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas usando un *await* de mas.

Una vez llamada a la api `(resultado = await fetch('...'))`, y pasado el resultado a json `(resultado = await resultado.json())` ya no hay mas llamadas asíncronas que hacer por lo que el await no es necesario, 'getres2' no devuelve una Promesa por lo que no tiene sentido poner `setUniversidad(await getres2);`. Elimina ese *await*.

Después para pasar el valor del `<SELECT>` a los inputs debes pasar a la propiedad *value* del option no solo getCon2.nombre, sino getCon2.nombre + getCon2.documento para poder manejar ambos valores mas tarde tal que asi:

```
 <option
   key={getcon2.id}
   value={`${getcon2.documento}-${getcon2.name}`}
  >
```

Estableces 2 referencias para los inputs con el hook [useRef](https://es.react.dev/reference/react/useRef):

```
const nombre_input = useRef();
const documento_input = useRef();
```

Para que esas referencias apunten a los inputs (inicialmente no apuntan a nada) debes definir los inputs con su propiedad *ref* y colocando las referencias como su valor:

```
<input ref={nombre_input} type="text"></input>
<input ref={documento_input} type="text"></input>
```

Defines una función que se ejecutara cada vez que el `<SELECT>` cambie de valor, validando primero que ese valor no este vacío ni que sea `'--Seleccione --'` para luego tomar ese valor, dividir la cadena en 2 y pasar una mitad a un input y la otra mitad al otro usando las referencias:

```
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.value && e.target.value !== "--Seleccione --") {
      const [documento, name] = e.target.value.split("-");
      nombre_input.current.value = name;
      documento_input.current.value = documento;
    }
  };
```

Finalmente solo te queda pasar esa función al evento *onChange* del `<SELECT>`:

```
<select onChange={handleChange} className="form-select">
```

Puedes ver y probar el código final [aqui](https://codesandbox.io/embed/adoring-mestorf-tg96mg?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).

Comment: muchas gracias por la observación, pero me puedes ayudar con la pregunta que realice en este post.

Comment: @Giovanny si disculpa ahi modifico la respuesta

Comment: pregunto si tuviera otro input donde el primero aparezca el documento y el segundo el nombre en el momento de seleccionar el registro en el select como seria?

Comment: la solución que diste tiene un problema y es con los espacios, por ejemplo si coloco primero el nombre en la constante y luego el documento en los campos input me va aparecer en el primer input el nombre  y en el segundo input el primer apellido y no el documento , ya que el nombre lleva aparte del nombre primer y segundo apellido separado por un espacio.

Comment: @Giovanny si lo note mira ahora con el link nuevo, separo con '-' en lugar de espacio.

Comment: @Giovanny ahi divide el documento en un campo y el nombre y el apellido en otro, eso despues lo administras como quieres creo que se entiende mas o menos la idea.